# How to properly generate Facebook Graph API App Secret Proof in Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am making a server side Facebook Graph API call to the `all_mutual_friends` edge: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-context/all_mutual_friends/

The call works when the two users are friends, but returns no useful data when they users aren't friends. According to the docs, this is because I must sign the call with the `appsecret_proof` parameter. No matter what I try, I am not able to successfully pass this parameter. I am using **jsrsasign** running on Parse. I have tried every configuration of using the `access token` as the message and my `appSecret` as the key, and vice versa. I have also tried multiple combinations of utf8 and hex. Every time I receive the error: *invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument*

Code:

```
  var Signer = require("cloud/vendor/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js");
  var userId = request.params.userId;
  var accessToken = request.params.accessToken;
  var appSecret = "redactedStringPastedFromFacebook";

  var signer = new Signer.Mac({alg: "hmacsha256", pass: appSecret});
  var appSecretString = signer.doFinalString(accessToken);
  var appSecretHex = signer.doFinalHex(accessToken);

  var graphRequestURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" + userId;
  var fields = "?fields=context.fields(all_mutual_friends.fields(name,picture.width(200).height(200)))";
  //var authorization = "&access_token=" + accessToken; //this works, but only for existing friends
  var authorization = "&access_token=" + accessToken + "&appsecret_proof=" + appSecretHex;
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: graphRequestURL + fields + authorization,
    method: "GET",
  })
```

Most examples I have seen are in PHP or Python and the crypto routines are a bit more clear. This works in that both `appSecretString` and `appSecretHex` don't throw errors and look reasonable, however the values are always rejected by Facebook.

Notes:

- I have triple checked the App Secret value provided by Facebook
- I have been approved by Facebook to use the all_mutual_friends feature, which is a requirement for this particular call
- I am using Parse, which isn't Node, and can't use NPM modules that have external dependencies, which is why I am using **jsrsasign**. I also tried using **CryptoJS** directly, but it is no longer maintained and doesn't have proper module support and **jsrsasign** seems to wrap it anyway.

Comment: Have you used the PHP snippet in the documentation to generate an app secret proof? That way you can compare it with what you're generating.

Comment: No, but that is a good idea assuming I can set up an equivalent and working PHP environment to run that snippet. I will try that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
  import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

  const accessToken = <your_page_access_token>;
  const clientSecret = <your_app_client_secret>;
  const appsecretProof = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(accessToken, clientSecret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```